# Meaning of これはない

Tags: meaning

> 『……あのさぁ、あたしもキミたちの目的はわかってるつもりよ？でもさすがに**これはない**んじゃないの？朱鷺夜を冒瀆しただけじゃ飽き足らず、今度はあたしの純心まで弄んでさぁ』

Hi. What does the bold これはない mean here? Like ひどい?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A similar meaning to [それはない](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/) which has the follow definition:

Japanese: 相手の言動を強く非難・否認するときに用いる言葉。

English: Words used to strongly condemn or repudiate the words or actions of another.

In the context of the excerpt provided I might translate 「でもさすがにこれはないんじゃないの？」 as "Isn't this a bit too much / far?" (following on to the next part of the excerpt).